# Getting in this error what i have to change Column check constraint 'machine_chk_2' references other

Tags: mysql, rdbms, check-constraints

```
CREATE TABLE machine.machine (
    m_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    mname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    mprice FLOAT CHECK (mprice > 0),
    mcost FLOAT CHECK (mcost < mprice)
);
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but I recommend to use `DECIMAL` for currency values, not `FLOAT`. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: What's your question? Where is the `Column check constraint 'machine_chk_2`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are getting this error:

> ERROR 3813 (HY000): Column check constraint 'machine_chk_2' references other column.

The reason is documented:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

> - A column constraint appears within a column definition and can refer only to that column.

If you need a check constraint to reference two or more columns, you must make it a table-level constraint. In this case, it's simple:

```
CREATE TABLE machine (
  m_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  mname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  mprice FLOAT CHECK (mprice > 0),
  mcost FLOAT,
  CHECK (mcost < mprice)
)
```

It just means to separate the `mcost` column definition from the constraint definition with a comma (`,`).